Prefetching complex query that does a Union
I'm trying to prefetch a related object to optimize performance. The code I'm trying to Prefetch is this;
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_attribute_values(self):
        # ToDo: Implement this prefetch.
        if hasattr(self, "_prefetched_attribute_values"):
            return self._prefetched_attribute_values

        if not self.pk:
            return self.attribute_values.model.objects.none()

        attribute_values = self.attribute_values.all()
        if self.is_child:
            parent_attribute_values = self.parent.attribute_values.exclude(
                attribute__code__in=attribute_values.values("attribute__code")
            )
            return attribute_values | parent_attribute_values

        return attribute_values

What this does is the following;

Get all attribute_values of itself, attribute_values is a related model ProductAttributeValue
If it's a child, also get the parent attribute_values, but exclude attribute_values with attribute__codes that are already present in the child attribute_values result
Do a union that combines them together.

Currently, I have this prefetch;
Prefetch(
    "attribute_values",
    queryset=ProductAttributeValueModel.objects.select_related(
        "attribute", "value_option"
    )
),

This works for the non child scenario, but unfortunately, there are a lot of child products and thus the performance isn't as great.
So ideally, I can prefetch the combined attributes to '_prefetched_attribute_values', though I would be fine with doing two prefetches as well;

For the product itself
For the parent, but still needs to exclude attributes that the child itself had

I have tried doing it with a Subquery & OuterRef, but no luck yet.

I ended up with the following solution, which seems to work.
        # The base queryset for both self and parent attribute values.
        prefetch_queryset = (
            ProductAttributeValue.objects.all()
            .select_related("attribute", "value_option", "value_option__group")
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "value_multi_option",
                    queryset=AttributeOption.objects.select_related("group"),
                )
            )
            .annotate(code=F("attribute__code"))
        )

        # Subquery to get the child's attribute codes
        child_attribute_codes = ProductAttributeValue.objects.filter(
            product=OuterRef("product__children")
        ).values("attribute__code")

        parent_prefetch_queryset = prefetch_queryset.exclude(
            Exists(
                child_attribute_codes.filter(
                    attribute__code=OuterRef("attribute__code")
                )
            )
        )

        # pylint: disable=not-callable
        queryset = self.select_related("parent").prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "attribute_values",
                queryset=prefetch_queryset,
                to_attr="_prefetched_attribute_values",
            ),
            Prefetch(
                "parent__attribute_values",
                queryset=parent_prefetch_queryset,
                to_attr="_prefetched_parent_attribute_values",
            ),
        )

